# I want to know how transformed "a-(a%b) " to "a&(~b)" (snapping grid formula)

Tags: gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

When I searching about Snapping grid function. Actually it is Tile Collide.(You maybe know I learning GMS2 because of tags..)

It is not important for my question.

Cut to the chase, I learned about this formula.

```
pos.x - (pos.x % gridwidth)  <- this is number calculation.
```

It worked well what I want to. And I found different formula.

This formula is working for collision of obj and tiles.

```
(pos.x)&~(gridwidth-1)    <- this is binary calculation.
```

And It has same work. What happen?? I can't understand how these formula are transformed..

Actually I understand '&' has same work with subtract. 
But I don't understand others.

for example

```
var f1,f2;
var pos_x = 102;
var gridwidth = 64; // It must be even power of 2.
f1 = pos_x - (pos_x % gridwidth);
f2 = (pos_x)&(~(gridwidth-1));
```

Comment: why python and c# tag at the same time? What language is this?

Comment: GML is a script language for GameMaker Studio2
I thought GML base on Python.. just my guess.
I'm sorry if you confused about that.

And I delete C# tag because of it's confusion.

Comment: Does grid width have to be an even power of 2?  That's the only way I see the second formula making any sense. - if so, then both of these are "snapping" to a multiple of an even power of two, that even power of two being `gridwidth`.

Comment: provide potential values for pos.x and gridwidth? because these two formulas are not equivalent at all. for example, with 10 and 3 
`x - (x % gridwidth) #9` and 

`(x)&~(gridwidth-1) #8`

Comment: Oh I see.. I added an example what I did for it.

Comment: Cool.  So does my answer explain what's going on well enough for you to understand it?

Comment: Yes!! My trouble is solved, thanks for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two formulas are only equivalent if `gridwidth` is an even power of two, like 128, 256, 2048, etc.

In either case, `pos.x - (pos.x % gridwidth)` is doing a `floor` back to an even multiple of `gridwidth`, "snapping" to the start of that grid cell, where the grid consists of cells of width `gridwidth`.

If you can assume `gridwidth` is an even power of 2, then `(pos.x)&~(gridwidth-1)` is doing the same thing.  Basically, given this assumption, every value in one grid cell will only differ in its lower order bits...the bits below the `gridwidth` bit.  This code is just clearing those bits, thereby calculating the result to a be an even multiple of `gridwidth`, which will be the first position in that cell of the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. As you said, second formula has same work with first formula when `gridwidth` has even number.

Comment: Not just any even number though...an even power of 2 only.  This won't work for a grid width of 10, or 1000. - I figure that's what you meant.  Just making sure.